# PyPI 403 on Upload

Tags: python, pypi

I'm trying to upload a new package I've created to PyPI, but I'm getting the following error each time:

```
403 Client Error: You are not allowed to upload to 'smuggler'.
```

Given that there's [no existing package with that name](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smuggler), I'm not sure why it's being blocked. I also upload it to [the PyPI test site](https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/smuggler) without any issues.

Comment: Can you upload other packages? Is it the package content that's being blocked? Is it the name?

Comment: I don't really have another package to upload, so I'm not sure. I'm starting to think there might be a throttle of sorts on new accounts.